# Como saber qual condicional está dando true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Por exemplo, tenho o seguinte `if`:

```
if(!condicao1 || !condicao2 || !condicao3){
  retorno erro com a condiçao que nao existe
}
```

Quando ele entrar nesse `if` eu gostaria de saber qual dos parâmetros esta faltando para retornar um erro.

Comment: Para saber qual, é necessário que elas estejam separadas em condições diferentes.

Comment: Se for mais de um você quer retornar todos ou o primeiro apenas?

Comment: É importante marcar ✓ a resposta que mais lhe ajudou.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: Dá um `console.log` em cada uma delas ;)

Answer (score 12):

É simples, se você quer saber individualmente tem que fazer individualmente:

```
if (!condicao1) {
    //Faça o que precisa aqui
}
if (!condicao2) {
    //Faça o que precisa aqui
}
if (!condicao3) {
    //Faça o que precisa aqui
}
```

Eventualmente pode fazer algo geral também:

```
if (!condicao1 || !condicao2 || !condicao3) {
    //faz algo geral aqui
    if (!condicao1) {
        //Faça o que precisa aqui
    }
    if (!condicao2) {
        //Faça o que precisa aqui
    }
    if (!condicao3) {
        //Faça o que precisa aqui
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Operators/Comparison.js).

Comment: +1 porque tambem funciona. :)

Answer (score 4):

> Me pareceu um conflito do título com o texto da pergunta: *faltando* =
>   `false`? Levei em conta o título por estar mais claro que deseja saber qual está dando `true`.

Se quer saber se apenas **1** dos parâmetros é `true`, pode fazer assim:

```js
condicao1 = false;
condicao2 = true;
condicao3 = false;

if(!condicao1 || !condicao2 || condicao3){
    if(condicao1 || condicao2){
        if(condicao1){
            alert("condicao1 é true");
        }else{
            alert("condicao2 é true");
        }
    }else{
        alert("condicao3 é true");
    }
}
```

Ou pode fazer direto:

```js
condicao1 = false;
condicao2 = true;
condicao3 = false;

if(condicao1 || condicao2){
    if(condicao1){
        alert("condicao1 é true");
    }else{
        alert("condicao2 é true");
    }
}else{
    alert("condicao3 é true");
}
```